# How to resolve this in linear regression in R

Tags: linear-model

[image]

Linear model on yearly return calculated on Dow 30 companies

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to resolve, really.  You have told R to do something and it did it. But what you told it to do doesn't make sense.

You have 30 stocks and 30 data points.  There's nothing to regress as the sample size matches the number of parameters so every parameter fits perfectly, but the regression is pointless as you already knew the returns.

If you want to do something like this, you would need returns for these companies from many years.